# Unit test fails with release config but passes in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

My unit test:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void LogAdjustment()
{
    //arrange
    var mrNumber = 123456;
    var adjustmentAmount = 2.0f;
    var startingWeight = 13.0f;
    var expectedWeight = startingWeight + adjustmentAmount;
    var startingRecord = new MasterRecord
    {
        Number = mrNumber,
        AcceptableNetWeight = startingWeight,
        QVolume = startingWeight / 1.031f
    };
    var poolRecord = new PoolRecord { MasterNumber = mrNumber };

    var iStoreMock = new Mock<IStore>();
    iStoreMock.Setup(s => s.GetReceipt(mrNumber)).Returns(startingRecord);
    iStoreMock.Setup(s => s.GetPool(mrNumber)).Returns(poolRecord);
    iStoreMock.Setup(s => s.RecordReceipt(It.Is<MasterRecord>(r => r.AcceptableNetWeight == expectedWeight && r.QVolume == expectedWeight / 1.031f));
    iStoreMock.Setup(s => s.GetReceipt(mrNumber)).Returns(startingRecord);

    var recorder = new ReceiptRecorder(iStoreMock.Object);
    var adjustment = new Adjustment { LotId = _clearAcceptableNumber, Adjustment = adjustmentAmount };

    //act
    recorder.LogAdjustment(adjustment);

    //assert
    iStoreMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

The above test fails with the following error in Release mode:

> Moq.MockVerificationException: The following setups were not matched:
> IStoreMock s => s.RecordReceipt(It.Is(r => r.AcceptableNetWeight == 15 && r.QVolume == 14.54898))

This exact same test passes when I run it in Debug mode.

Comment: Could it be that you are using the compilation flags and your `RELEASE` interface signature changes?

Comment: I have no tags set up explicitly anywhere. can you elaborate on what you want me to check zaitsman?

Comment: I don't know if this is the real problem, but in `r.QVolume == 14.54898` you should never be checking a floating point number for an exact match. Does the testing library have methods for checking for almost identical floating point values?

Comment: Inspect the Invocations sequence on the mock, it'll confirm what was actually received. Check that against your Verify expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ken Y-N, rounding the float numbers in the setup helped in passing the unit tests in both Debug and Release modes.

```cs
iStoreMock.Setup(s => s.RecordReceipt(
   It.Is<MasterRecord>(r => r.AcceptableNetWeight == expectedWeight 
       && Math.Round(r.QuarantineVolume, 5) == Math.Round((expectedWeight/1.031f), 5)));
```